# Log4Net Log to specific Appender .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, log4net

Using .NET Core, C#, Log4Net 2.0.8

I am trying to log to different Appenders but for some reason there is no log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(string), there is only log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(type).

I have taken an example from:
[Log4net - Logging to wrong appender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45234344/log4net-logging-to-wrong-appender)

I wish to log from one class:

```
private static readonly ILog logA = LogManager.GetLogger("LogA");
log.Debug("This should log to LogA");
```

And in another other class:

```
private static readonly ILog logB = LogManager.GetLogger("LogB");
log.Debug("This should log to LogB");
```

I have tried understanding Log4Net following https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/introduction.html

But the example also refers to:

```
ILog x = LogManager.GetLogger("wombat");
ILog y = LogManager.GetLogger("wombat");
```

How do I log to specific Appenders? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use the `GetLogger(Assembly repositoryAssembly, string name)` overload, see [spec](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/M_log4net_LogManager_GetLogger.htm).

An `assembly` argument must be passed in, which can be e.g. `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`.

*(Note that this logs to a specific logger, not an appender, which is what you are trying to do.)*

Example:

```
ILog logger = LogManager .GetLogger(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), "LogB");
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this out. I thought the entry in the Log.config is an appender and Loggers contain many appenders depending on the log.config file I use?

Comment: True, it is that both loggers and appenders are defined in the config file; the name passed to `GetLogger` is the name of the logger, which outputs via its appenders.
Just to avoid confusion as the title of your post says 'log to specific appender' ...

Comment: Ah! I understand now! Thanks so much!