# log4net: dismember exception

Tags: c#, log4net

I want to separate exception's stack trace from their message. for instance in this example:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.
>    at
>   BettweenSvc.Bettweensvc.processRequest(RequestManagerRepository rmr,
>   RequestConversation rc) in
>   C:\Repository\bettween\trunk\Solution\BettweenSvc\Bettweensvc.cs:line
>   277
>     at BettweenSvc.Bettweensvc.bettweenTimer_Elapsed(Object
>   sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) in
>   C:\Repository\bettween\trunk\Solution\BettweenSvc\Bettweensvc.cs:line
>   111

I want to log

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.

in one field and the rest in another

Currently I have

```
<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@exception" />
  <dbType value="String" />
  <size value="2000" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
</parameter>
```

in my AdoNetAppender, how would I do this?

Comment: You cruel man - poor exception :(

Comment: I couldn't come up with a better name :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@exception" />
  <dbType value="String" />
  <size value="2000" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%exception{message}" />
  </layout>
</parameter>
```

If you want the stacktrace you use `%exception{stacktrace}`.

**EDIT**:
If you are using log4net 1.2.10 then you need to implement your own pattern layout that does what you want. I recommend to check the current log4net source code (trunk) to see how they do it (it is quite simple really). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183121/how-to-convert-my-decimal-thread-id-to-hex-and-make-it-appear-in-hex-format-in-lo/3184594#3184594) is an example of such a layout converter.

Comment: That doesn't work, it just outputs the same as `log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout`.

Comment: Are you really using PatternLayout instead of ExceptionLayout? I just tested it and it works as expected.

Comment: Ok, maybe this feature is implemented in the last revision of log4net (that is not published). I will check if the feature was already implemented in 1.2.10

Comment: This feature is indeed not in 1.2.10